# Most efficient way to check if two vectors are parallel

Tags: c++, vector, geometry, computation-theory

Given two vectors `u=(ux,uy,uz)` and `v=(vx,vy,vz),` what is the computationally cheapest way of checking whether they are parallel or *nearly* parallel (given some threshold to approximate), assuming the vectors are not normalized?

Regarding *nearly* parallel: for instance we assume a threshold up to first decimal part, e.g., if their cross product is `0.01` we can safely assume them to be parallel. We can similarly relax the condition for other methods we may want to use.

If it is preferred to adhere to a programming language to answer, let us assume we want to do this in c++.

- Computing the angle between them is costly because it requires using inverse trigonometric functions.
- Computing their cross product may be a way but not sure if it is the most efficient one.
- Normalizing them and verifying if their scalar product is one.

Comment: I miss the most obvious on your list: normalize them and calculate the scalarproduct

Comment: btw for 2 vectors with 3 entries you shouldnt worry about what is computationlly cheapest.

Comment: @user463035818 I have to say I disagree with both of your comments. Normalising the vectors is not at all cheap and if you have many vectors, you might care about what the fastest way to solve this is.

Comment: @user463035818 Indeed another potentially cheap method. Of course it is assumed that this operation will be repeated millions of times, hence the optimality question.

Comment: @Qubit well one actually doesnt need to normalize the vectors, one just needs to know the product of their length. Unless you think 2 is many we dont disagree ;)

Comment: Why do you need to normalize? If v and w are parallel then (v . w)^2 = ||v|| ||w|| and you can do that without square roots or inverse trig functions. If you want to approximate using a threshold, the cross-product option only requires three multiplications, two additions and a length.

Comment: Programming language isn't the concern here.   The dot product of two vectors is equal to the product of their lengths multiplied by the cosine of the angle between them.   You'll need to define what you mean by "nearly parallel" though.

Comment: @CompuChip So you mean, calculating the scalar product, then simply squaring it and checking if it equates the product of norms? by the way, the rhs of your condition assumes we know the norms of the vectors, so we have already calculated the norms (same cost as normalizing then).

Comment: You may use boost ... Basic Linear Algebra ... https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_37_0/libs/numeric/ublas/doc/index.htm ... I don't think there is a more optimal code.

Comment: @user929304 if you have N vectors and compare all pairs you need N^2 comparsions, but only N times calculate their length, so I wouldnt worry too much about that part

Comment: @Peter I also think the dot product path is the cheapest, so to simply check if their dot (scalar) product equates *nearly* the product of their norms. So I guess we have to know the norms anyway...Which begs to ask, what is the cheapest way of calculating vector norms?

Comment: @user929304 Note, the norms CompuChip used are the squares of the length, so you don't need to calculate the square root either.

Comment: @Qubit so we'd basically calculate `(ux*vx+uy*vy+uz*vz)^2 = (ux^2 + uy^2 + uz^2) * (vx^2 + vy^2 + vz^2)` in terms of operations, right?

Comment: btw I would probably refer to the numerical recipes. Their code is terribly outdated, their algorithms have some serious flaws, but often it helps to get some first idea of what can be done

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*Short answer:* **Theoretically, it doesn't matter at all. Practically: measure it**

*Long answer:*

Agreeing that the inverse trigonometric functions are out of the question, let's compare the most efficient ways of calculating the last two options.

### Computing their cross product

Since you allow for the vectors to be *nearly* parallel, you need to calculate

```
crossx := uy * vz + uz * vy;
crossy := ...;
crossz := ...;
crossNorm = crossx * crossx + crossy * crossy + crossz * crossz;
```

which involves 9 multiplications and 5 additions. If the vectors are (nearly) parallel then `crossNorm`  should be (nearly) zero.

However, as correctly noted by [Baum mit Augen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52165029/most-efficient-way-to-check-if-two-vectors-are-parallel?noredirect=1#comment91280281_52165376), it is sufficient to check that `crossx`, `crossy` and `crossz` are almost zero, reducing this to 6 multiplications and 3 additions, at the expense of up to two more comparisons. Which is more efficient, depends on the details of your language and definition of "nearly" equal – e.g. if nearly equals means that `fabs(...) < 1E-6` it may be worth only having to do it once.

### Calculating the scalar product

The scalar product is

```
scalar = ux * vx + uy * vy + uz * vz;
```

If the vectors are (nearly) parallel then

```
scalar * scalar
```

should (nearly) equal

```
(ux * ux + uy * uy + uz * uz) * (vx * vx + vy * vy + vz * vz).
```

This comes down to 10 multiplications and 6 additions.

### Normalizing them and verifying if their scalar product is one.

This is just the above calculation but with two extra `double` divisions. This does not add any value, in fact it may just introduce rounding problems.

### Conclusion

The number of double operations is nearly the same for both options. If you really want to know, you can compare the assembly https://godbolt.org/z/nJ9CXl but the difference is going to be minimal for all practical purposes. In fact, if you only count the "expensive"  instructions (`mulsd`, `addsd`, `subsd`) and the comparisons (`ucomisd`) both options have five of them. However, again, if you must know *exactly*, measure it!

Comment: You don't really need to compute `crossNorm`, checking if every single component of the cross vector is almost zero is enough.

Comment: @BaummitAugen Right, but we need to perform the *nearly equal* operation more times now! For instance in Python, we'd have to call `numpy.isclose()` 3 times instead of 1.

Comment: @user929304 Very true. Which variant wins probably depends mostly on how well your target systems' branch predictors can handle your input data. As CompuChip correctly advices, you should measure that. I've seen this type of optimization go either way.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and the clear write-up! Btw, I've noticed people barely ever upvote questions, they only do so for answer, it is a pity.

Comment: Oh, and when checking each component individually, you can potentially break out early, giving you a best case of 2 multiplications, one addition and on comparison. That might also be something to try.

Comment: @BaummitAugen nice! and I will set up my basis (coordinate system) such that one of the two vectors is parallel to a basis vector (so one non-zero component, basically building the basis starting from vector `u` as first eigenvector and so on) this way one component has to be checked.

Comment: @user929304 If you can set up that basis transformation in an efficient way, that does sound like an idea worth investigating. You'd still get up to two non-zero components in the cross product, though.

Comment: Forgive me if I'm stupid, but I can't seem to get the desired results using the second method. For example u=(0,1244,0) and v=(0.08,20,0). With that input the difference between scalar\*scalar and dot\*dot is ~9869. If I'd normalize the vectors (which I want to avoid) then they fall well within my 'tolerance'

Answer (score 0):

I think this is wrong

scalar=l1*l2*cos(r)=ux * vx + uy * vy + uz * vz
scalar^2=(l1*l2*cos(r))^2=(ux * vx + uy * vy + uz * vz)^2

(l1*l2)^2= (ux * ux + uy * uy + uz * uz) * (vx * vx + vy * vy + vz * vz)
so
cos(x)^2 =scalar^2/(ux * ux + uy * uy + uz * uz) * (vx * vx + vy * vy + vz * vz)=
(ux * vx + uy * vy + uz * vz)^2
/(ux * ux + uy * uy + uz * uz) * (vx * vx + vy * vy + vz * vz)

x is near 0 or 180 when cos is 1 or -1 so cos(x)^2 -> 1

when this

formila is near 1

(ux * vx + uy * vy + uz * vz)^2
/(ux * ux + uy * uy + uz * uz) * (vx * vx + vy * vy + vz * vz)
this means vectors are parralel